# ANT Design Push Pull Confusion

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, antd

I have two columns with setup like this:

```
<Row>
    <Col xs={24} lg={12}>
        <p>Column 1</p>
    </Col>
    <Col xs={24} lg={12}>
        <p>Column 2</p>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

How can I use `push` or `pull` from the [ANT Design Doc](https://ant.design/components/grid/#components-grid-demo-sort) to make Column 2 to be above Column 1 in smaller screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't push/pull on the xs column because each column takes up the full width. Instead we can put column 2 on top initially and change the order when the viewport is large. At the large breakpoint we can push Column 2 to the right and pull Column 1 to the left.

The [Grid API](https://ant.design/components/grid/#Col) allows us to pass objects containing props such as `span`, `push`, and `pull` for the breakpoint.

```js
<Row>
  <Col xs={24} lg={{span: 12, push: 12}}>
    <p>Column 2</p>
  </Col>
  <Col xs={24} lg={{span: 12, pull: 12}}>
    <p>Column 1</p>
  </Col>
</Row>
```